# How to ignore extra spaces in LDPA search filter?

Tags: javascript, search, ldap, whitespace

I have a node.js application that accesses AD through LDAP

I have a filter that looks like this: `filter: '(name = ' + inputString);`
Where inputString might be a name that looks like `'John Smith'`

But I found that inside the AD, some entries have extra white spaces Eg.

`'John  Smith' //with two spaces between the first name and last name.`

And my filter would not be able to pick it up. So how do I deal with this?

If it helps, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options come to mind:

**Option#1**: use the "approximately equal to" operator like this:

```
filter: '(name ~= ' + inputString);
```

**Option#2**: search by a different attribute or combination of attributes if available. The person's name is sometimes not reliable and most importantly it might not be unique. A better option will be using a unique attribute such as the username, email, etc...

Hope this helps.